# Ocultar animación al finalizar con lottie

Tags: android-studio

Tengo una animación con lottie, como puedo hacer para que se oculte al finalizar.

```
loading.setAnimation(R.raw.loading)
        loading.playAnimation()
        loading.repeatCount = 1
```

Si es posible puedo detectar cuando la pagina de mi webview se ha terminado de cargar por completo, para así poder ocultar la animación.

```
web.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){

        }
        web.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){

        }
        val setting: WebSettings = web.settings
        setting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        web.loadUrl(urlwebs)
```

**EDITADO**
logre que la animación se oculte con lo siguiente, funciona bien.

```
loading.animate()
            .alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(3000)
            .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    loading.visibility = View.GONE  //parece no funcionar solo se oculta porque se ha haciendo transparente hasta desaparecer
                }
            })
```

Funciona bien, pero creo que lo que hace esto es iniciar una nueva animación, es decir remplazar a la primera animación y luego oculta solo la animación que quedo. Mi propósito principal era ocultar la animación sin tener que agregar una nueva.

**La segunda parte aun no logro resolverla como dije tengo un webview, quisiera que la animación se oculte cuando la pagina se allá cargado totalmente.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"es posible puedo detectar cuando la pagina de mi webview se ha terminado de cargar por completo, para así poder ocultar la animación."

Esto lo puedes realizar configurando un [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) en su método [onPageFinished()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) notifica cuando la carga finalizó , aquí es donde debes configurar termine la animación.

```
    web.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient(){
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            // Carga inicia
            ...
            ...                
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            // Carga finalizo
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
```

Para finalizar la animación puedes usar:

```
loading.loop(false);
```

o también:

```
 loading.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: no puedo usar override tengo este error "onPageStarted' overrides nothing".

Comment: Funciona muy bien, estaba probandolo en el WebChromeClient() por eso el error

Comment: Si, debes usar WebViewClient no WebChromeClient().